# Groovy script that obtain TestCase name that has a run TestCase step

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have two Test Suites, in the first Test Suite I have a Test Case with step "Run TestCase" that will run a test case from the second Test Suite. I would like to have a groovy script in a second Test Suite that will provide me a Test Case name from a first Test Suite.

Note: I can't provide those names by myself, it has to be done automaticly.

Is it possible to get a Test Case name which has a run TestCase step?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get hold of that step which has a "run TestCase step

// **explanation** :- Got an iterator for TestSuite. Using that iterator going through all the testcases and then through all test steps

// then checking if any teststep has that name "Run TestCase"

This was you can find the test step under that testsuite in any of the testcases.

```
for(tc in testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseList())
{
for(ts in  tc.getTestStepList())
  {
   if( ts.getName()=="Run TestCase")
   {
    log.info "Found that step "
    log.info "TestCaseName = " + tc.getName()
    log.info "TestSuiteName = " + testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getName()

  }
 }
}
```

You can go one beyond up at project level and check under all suites by making an 
outer loop

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getTestSuiteList()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your target testCase (1b), create a 'caller' custom property.
Then, in your source testCase (1a), before the 'run test case step' create a groovy script to recover your test name :

```
    testName = testRunner.testCase.name
    return testName
```

When you do the run test case step, set ${Groovy Script#result} as a value for the 'caller' property

Then in your target's groovy step, recover the caller's value doing

```
    def caller = context.expand( '${#TestCase#caller}' )
    log.info caller
```

It's not very straightforward but it may fulfill your need

Alexandre